# Need help installing Google Chrome and other applications

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I currently need to use my computer for my online college courses. However, I am not able to install the programs I need, such as my bookstore app and Google Chrome.

How can I install these applications? I've had no luck searching for the answers online.

I am also trying to update Google. Ubuntu is directing me to an update page but does not perform any actions after that.

Comment: Is the bookstore app a Chrome extension or is it separate software? What is it called?

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? What app do you need or what task do you need done? Like names, versions, file types, etc. If the entire school is using such Ubuntu PCs, they must have found some good use for it. Perhaps you need productivity apps, not (just) Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu desktop, try and check this link below(14.04 version):

https://lecturesnippets.com/lesson/installing-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-14-04-desktop/

I would certainly recommend going to Software Center (Open the “Applications” menu. Ubuntu Software Center is at the bottom). then check for Chrome.

You can also try and open any browser (Firefox by default) and go to

https://google.com/chrome

You can follow the instructions there to install it (click the download button and go from there).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome** is not available in the repos.  The first result you'll get when you type **chrome** on google, will send you to the page where you can download **Chrome for Linux**.

Google will detect that you're looking for a Linux version and direct you there automatically but it will not detect your exact system.  Since you're using Ubuntu, the correct option is **.deb**.

Be aware that only 64-bit chrome is supported and you can use it as long as a 64-bit Ubuntu is installed on your system.  If not, your only alternative is to install **Chromium** instead, which is definitely available in the repos.